# Merging three queries into single results

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have three queries that all return 1 row and 1 column. I would like to return this as 1 row, and three columns.

My queries

```
select count(distinct rt) from gpstable where rt >  GETDATE() - '1 day'::INTERVAL AND di like 'i';
select count(distinct rt) as count from gpstable where rt >  GETDATE() - '1 day'::INTERVAL group by di order by count limit 1;
select count(distinct rt) as count from gpstable where rt >  GETDATE() - '1 day'::INTERVAL group by di order by count DESC limit 1;
```

This is what I have tried

```
select userCount, min, max 
from 
(select count(distinct rt) as userCount from gpstablev2 where rt >  GETDATE() - '1 day'::INTERVAL AND di like 'UmTqUo1MQU8FgXfXXGNFh7vZnQN+bt2ThIQIDHNnmWU=') as userCount,
(select count(distinct rt) as min from gpstablev2 where rt >  GETDATE() - '1 day'::INTERVAL group by di order by count limit 1) as min,
(select count(distinct rt) as max from gpstablev2 where rt >  GETDATE() - '1 day'::INTERVAL group by di order by count DESC limit 1) as max;
```

And I get the following error ERROR: column "count" does not exist in gpstablev2 [SQL State=42703]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You were close, you just need to put the individual statements into the `select` list, not the `from`:

```
select (select count(distinct rt) from gpstable where rt >  GETDATE() - '1 day'::INTERVAL AND di = 'i') as user_count,
       (select count(distinct rt) from gpstable where rt >  GETDATE() - '1 day'::INTERVAL group by di order by count limit 1) as min_count,
       (select count(distinct rt) from gpstable where rt >  GETDATE() - '1 day'::INTERVAL group by di order by count DESC limit 1) as max_ount;
```

But I think this can be simplified and reduced to a single query over the table:

```
select max(case when di = 'i' then di_count end) as user_count, 
       min(di_count) as min_count,
       max(di_count) as max_count
from (
    select di, 
           count(distinct rt) as di_count
    from gpstable 
    where rt >  current_date - interval '1' day
    group by di
)t ;
```

This only needs to go through the table once, instead of three times as in your attempt. That will be much more efficient. I only tested this on a very tiny dataset, so it might be that I missed something.

I used the ANSI SQL format to specify an interval `interval '1' day` because I prefer standard syntax whenever there is an equivalent version (that's also why I used `current_date` instead of `getdate()`. For the duration of "one day" this wouldn't actually be necessary, because the default unit is a day, so `current_date - 1` would work just as well.

Comment: So I am not sure why, maybe it is because I am using AWS Redshift and just a PSQL database. But your " current_date - interval '1' day" causes execution time to increase to about 15secs, where "GETDATE() - '1 day'::INTERVAL" keeps execute time below 1s. Not sure if I have some sort of caching going on...

Comment: @djc391: thanks for the feedback. This is really strange and I never have observed such a difference using a "normal" Postgres version. What about `current_date - 1`?